# Protocol adding sound to UIButton touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, protocols

I've created a protocol adding a function to play a sound:

```
protocol ButtonSound { }

extension ButtonSound where Self: UIButton {
    func clickSound() { AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104) }
}
```

But using this, I'll have to add `clickSound` to `touchesBegan` for each custom button class manually.

Is it possible to make an extension of `UIButton` which only conforms to the `ButtonSound` protocol and override `touchesBegan` there?

Comment: As Apple puts it in their Protocol-Oriented Programming video, "don't fight the system". Cocoa Touch is Object-Oriented. Sometimes it makes sense to just subclass. Given you really want to override the superclass, why don't you just do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't override a superclass method in a protocol extension. As others have said, this is a case for subclassing.